# Myface CODI is not throwing exceptions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, myfaces, codi

I do JSF development using Myfaces, Primefaces, Tomcat in Eclipse IDE. When testing thru I used to get exceptions thrown by Myfaces/Primefaces in the Eclipse Console.

Recently I enhanced my development environment by adding MyFaces CODI and OpenWebBeans. Ever since I have done this, I stopped gettting any error messages in my eclipse console. I have no idea why.

Even basic errors like nullpointerexception, method/variable not found etc. are not thrown. I have set Myface CODI stage as Development. I get MyFace CODI messages related to start and stop of conversations, but all exceptions and errors are never thrown.

It is frustrating to debug myfaces/primefaces/bean code to discover these simple errors.

Can somebody suggest what could I do to get the exceptions back again in the Eclipse environment. 
Need some urgent help as this issue has slow down development very significantly.

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with your setup. We are using all of those libs as well and none of them can cause something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes. It is an issue with the set up. But I am not able to figure out the set up issue. I am not sure what I need to do to the set up. Any help/pointer would be great.